# Rendering over DirectX window with Awesomium (semi-transparent & rounded elements)

Tags: c++, css, awesomium

I wonder if it's possible to use Awesomium to render the GUI over the DirectX 11 game (I **do NOT use .NET**, it's C++/DirectX 11 game)?

It would involve:

1. Rendering the scene on the window with DirectX 11 (just as I am doing it now).
2. Rendering the GUI with Awesomium from HTML/CSS **over** the previously rendered scene.

Note that some GUI elements should be **semi-transparent or rounded** - so it's not only rendering on some rect, but also blending.

Is it possible? Or maybe I could make it another way (e.g. telling Awesomium to use DirectX for rendering somehow)?

Or maybe I could draw an **semi-transparent** DirectX texture in Awesomium, and then render it over the scene with DirectX? I know that rendering to texture resource is possible with Awesomium, but does it supports transparency & semi-transparency?

If not, are the good alternatives for what I wanted to achive with Awesomium?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It can be done.

If you look at the documentation of the Awesomium WebView class it has a surface() method which will return the views backing bitmap.

Here is some c++ documentation for the class.

http://awesomium.com/docs/1_7_0/cpp_api/class_awesomium_1_1_web_view.html

You can copy this bitmap to a texture in DirectX and render it as layer on top of your game creating your UI.

You also have to route and translate input into Awesomium. You can style your UI however you like using HTML, CSS and Javascript. You can make it rounded in this way and introduce transparency.

I won't repeat a perfectly good tutorial on doing this. You can find one here.

http://www.gamedev.net/blog/32/entry-2260646-sweet-snippets-rendering-web-pages-to-texture-using-awesomium-and-direct3d/

How you render your texture after it is written doesn't have anything to do with Awesomium. Choose your blend modes and/or use shaders with output texture for desired effect.

Comment: Thank you :) I have just one concern: copying the whole bitmap to texture each frame does not sounds good (fast enough) for real time rendering purposes. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Copying is expensive but remember that UI doesn't necessarily get updated every frame so ideally you only copy when there is an update to be made. Check the Awesomium surface with is_dirty() and only make update to DirectX when it is. It has  worked fine for me for fairly complex UI.